# Checking the dependency of Perl Module and Manual Add

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using `GNU\Linux` system and below perl version is been already installed.

```
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Here I want to install a perl module `Net::SFTP::Foreign` to build some script (say example `transfer_file.pl`)  which should transfer files from local server to remote server.

Problem is I don't have permission to install the modules. So what I was thinking is, let me create a `lib` directory where I am writing `transfer_file.pl` and manually create a directory/file `Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm` inside `lib` and add the content from `metacpan`. In this case I can use something like this in my transfer script shebang line - `#!/usr/bin/perl -I/path/to/the/current/location/lib`

I don't know whether it's a right approach or not, since I don't have permission to install anything in the server I thought of doing in this way.

Again, if I add `Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm` manually in `lib` folder obviously there would be dependency on `Net::SFTP::Foreign`, so dependency tree I am checking using **Gabor Szabo**'s script below in my local windows system:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
use MetaCPAN::API;

my $name = 'Net::SFTP::Foreign';

my $mcpan = MetaCPAN::API->new;
my $dist  = $mcpan->release( distribution => $name );
say Dumper $dist;
```

When I execute the above script I am getting below error:

```
Failed to fetch 'https://fastapi.metacpan.org/v1/release/Net::SFTP::Foreign': Not Found at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/MetaCPAN/API/Release.pm line 42.
```

1. What could be the problem here?
2. Any alternate ways to check the dependency in
   `https://metacpan.org/` site itself?
3. Even if above script executes properly do I need to add all the
   dependency modules manually? Is it necessary?

Comment: Try `my $name = 'Net-SFTP-Foreign'` instead of `my $name = 'Net::SFTP::Foreign'`

Comment: I would recommend using [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) for this

Comment: Note: The [module](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::API) says it has been deprecated and replaced by [MetaCPAN::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::Client)

Comment: @HåkonHægland How can I get dependency tree using `MetaCPAN::Client`. And how `perlbrew` helps me to install the modules.

Comment: *" How can I get dependency tree using MetaCPAN::Client"* : Try this `MetaCPAN::Client->new->release($name)->dependency()`

Comment: *"how perlbrew helps me to install the modules"* : You must first install it, then simply switch to the new perl with `perlbrew switch ..` and then install the module using `cpanm Net::SFTP::Foreign`

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland. But I am unable to install `perlbrew` in my server currently. Here is the message `]$ \curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'install.perlbrew.pl'
`

Comment: *"Couldn't resolve host 'install.perlbrew.pl"* : Strange, it works for me...Try if you can access the script from here instead: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/master/perlbrew-install

Comment: True, its strange. I have installed `perlbrew` in one of the `CentOS` system sometimes back. Yes I am able to access the link which you provided.

Comment: Please do not rewrite the question completely such that the original comments above become meaningless. Instead ask a new question, then roll back the last edit to this question.

Comment: Done @HåkonHægland.